# MySQL shows usage guidance when I attempt to load a database in Centos

Tags: mysql, linux

My script:

```
mysql -h localhost -u username -p password dbname < 2015022404041424718063.sql
```

It only reports this message that shows options:

```
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.95, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
```

I don't understand what is wrong with the command, but my database is 1073Mb. Here is a dump of the variables:

```
Variables (--variable-name=value)
and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}  Value (after reading options)
--------------------------------- -----------------------------
auto-rehash                       TRUE
character-sets-dir                (No default value)
default-character-set             latin1
comments                          FALSE
compress                          FALSE
database                          (No default value)
delimiter                         ;
vertical                          FALSE
force                             FALSE
named-commands                    FALSE
ignore-spaces                     FALSE
local-infile                      FALSE
no-beep                           FALSE
host                              localhost
html                              FALSE
xml                               FALSE
line-numbers                      TRUE
unbuffered                        FALSE
column-names                      TRUE
sigint-ignore                     FALSE
port                              0
prompt                            mysql>
quick                             FALSE
raw                               FALSE
reconnect                         FALSE
socket                            (No default value)
ssl                               FALSE
ssl-ca                            (No default value)
ssl-capath                        (No default value)
ssl-cert                          (No default value)
ssl-cipher                        (No default value)
ssl-key                           (No default value)
ssl-verify-server-cert            FALSE
table                             FALSE
debug-info                        FALSE
user                              username
safe-updates                      FALSE
i-am-a-dummy                      FALSE
connect_timeout                   0
max_allowed_packet                16777216
net_buffer_length                 16384
select_limit                      1000
max_join_size                     1000000
secure-auth                       FALSE
show-warnings                     FALSE
```

Comment: Please remove the oracle tag - your question apparently has nothing to do with Oracle (the Oracle tag is for the Oracle RDBMS, not for every product of Oracle corp).

Comment: there's no space after you issue `-p` - you need to supply the password immediately after that

Comment: @Sathya if i do that, one error will be show: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: that would mean the user is not allowed to login using that credentials

Comment: i don't know, but user name and pass is correct, i had try SQLyog and db imported.